# How to test a function that has been passed by props

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

If I have a component like this

```
import React from "react";

const GettingStarted = ({ object }) => <Button onPress={() => object.next()} />;
```

How would you test with jest that `object.next()` gets called inside the component?

Comment: What do you mean with "What is the problem with it?" I am asking how can I test a function that has been passed by props because I can not figure out how.

I have tried to create a mock function like `const object = {next: ()=> null}` but I can not `jest.spyOn` it because it is . not actually an instance of a component.

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that. I don't see why you can't `jest.spyOn(object, 'next')`. You could also build an object that contains a `jest.fn()`, rather than creating a redundant function to spy on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to spy on the function being passed to the `onPress`. Then, you would simulate an `onPress` event on the button and check that the spied upon function was called with any parameters, etc. Then you would test the actual output of the function. So, for example, if the function changes the text in the button from 'Click Me' to 'Clicked!', you would assert on the first text property before the click and then check the updated one.

Example with Jest:

```
const onPressSpy = jest.fn();

const gettingStartedButton = shallow(<GettingStarted object={onPressSpy} />);

expect(gettingStartedButton.find('button').children().text()).toBe('Click Me!');

gettingStartedButton.find('button').simulate('press');
expect(onPressSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(gettingStartedButton.find('button').children().text()).toBe('Clicked!');
```